# Using Named Ranges in VBA Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to access a named range from using VBA in Excel 2007. When I used the explicit range i.e. "A3:M53" I can get the formula below to work. However, when I replace the explicit range with a named range I get an error. I need to use named ranges as the program needs to select different ranges depending on what data is imported. Fixed.OAX.5 is a named range on the OAX50 worksheet.

```
WorksheetFunction.Match(5, Worksheets("OAX50").Range("Fixed.OAX.5"), 1)
```

When I run this code I get "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class.

Comment: Try removing the sheet reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're most probably not finding value `5` in `Worksheets("OAX50").Range("Fixed.OAX.5")`

use `Application.Match()` and wrap any possible error:

```
Dim x As Variant
With Worksheets("OAX50").Range("Fixed.OAX.5")
    x = Application.Match(5, .Cells, 1)
    If IsError(x) Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, no match for '5' in range " & .Address & " of worksheet '" & .Parent.Name & "'"
    Else
        'your code to exploit 'x'
    End If
End With
```

Comment: @physics90, did you get through it?

Comment: I'm about to try it with your suggestions.

Comment: that worked. Thanks a bunch. But why? Why can't I use worksheetfunction.match or worksheetfunction.index? And why can't I use the reference directly within the equation?

Comment: Using the WoksheetFunction _version_ of those methods brings along the need of handling errors should those method fail finding what you tell them to search for. While the Application _version_ wraps the error in the Variant return value that you can query with the IsError() function

Comment: The thing is there weren't any errors. The value 5 is in the table and was found when I switched to your method.

Comment: Why do you have '.' characters in your Named Range?  I have never seen tat before.  Basically, a Named Range is just a string.